# unable to retrieve the list of databases in Mysql

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2019

I'm using visual studio  2019 and MYSQL 8.0.31. Now the problem is I'm unable to get the database list in visual studio project. I'm reinstalling the mysql several times. I have my connectors and Nuget references mysql.data. But still I'm get the error.[image]

Please anyone help me . I'm new to Visual studio and mysql

Comment: hwo did you setup your mysql?

Comment: I'm download mysql installer for windows. Then I'm install step by step as per the procedure

Comment: use `xampp` or `mysql workbench`

Comment: mysql workbench I'm using